# Siunitx - significant stars (***) far away

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'm testing Stata → LaTeX integration, and reading some guides, I was satisfied with the results. Unfortunately, it seems that one can only use the `dcolumn` package in Stata. Knowing that the `siunitx` package is the one that many people prefer around here, I changed that part of the code manually. However, for some reason the stars ( `***` ) on 3673.1 are far away, and the `(` of the corresponding standard error estimate is not properly aligned. I am not sure what is wrong? Don't worry about the double estimates, I by mistake did not clear the `eststo` function.

Here is a picture:

[image]

The code doesn't look particularly clean to me (it is produced using the `esttab` command in Stata), but it does its job.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{This is a regression table\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}\\
\midrule
Weight (lbs.)       &       1.747\sym{**} &       3.465\sym{***}&       1.747\sym{**} &        3.465\sym{***}\\
                &     (0.641)         &     (0.631)         &     (0.641)         &       (0.631)         \\
\addlinespace
Mileage (mpg)       &      -49.51         &       21.85         &      -49.51         &       21.85         \\
                &     (86.16)         &     (74.22)         &     (86.16)         &     (74.22)         \\
\addlinespace
Car type            &                     &      3673.1\sym{***}&                     &      3673.1\sym{***}\\
                &                     &     (684.0)         &                     &     (684.0)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &      1946.1         &     -5853.7         &      1946.1         &     {-5853.7}         \\
                &    (3597.0)         &    (3377.0)         &    (3597.0)         &    (3377.0)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &          {74}         &          {74}         &          {74}         &          {74}         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &       0.273         &       0.478         &       0.273         &       0.478         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Source: UCT Institutional Planning Department}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \   (p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell `siunitx` two things:

1. Reserve the space for note marks.  This is done by the command `\sisetup{table-space-text-post = \sym{***}}`
2. Do not align the additional text, so it may be put close to the numbers: `\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S[table-align-text-post=false]}}`

Here is the result

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{This is a regression table\label{tab1}}
\sisetup{table-space-text-post = \sym{***}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S[table-align-text-post=false]}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}\\
\midrule
Weight (lbs.)       &       1.747\sym{**} &       3.465\sym{***}&       1.747\sym{**} &        3.465\sym{***}\\
                &     (0.641)         &     (0.631)         &     (0.641)         &       (0.631)         \\
\addlinespace
Mileage (mpg)       &      -49.51         &       21.85         &      -49.51         &       21.85         \\
                &     (86.16)         &     (74.22)         &     (86.16)         &     (74.22)         \\
\addlinespace
Car type            &                     &      3673.1\sym{***}&                     &      3673.1\sym{***}\\
                &                     &     (684.0)         &                     &     (684.0)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &      1946.1         &     -5853.7         &      1946.1         &     {-5853.7}         \\
                &    (3597.0)         &    (3377.0)         &    (3597.0)         &    (3377.0)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &          {74}         &          {74}         &          {74}         &          {74}         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &       0.273         &       0.478         &       0.273         &       0.478         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Source: UCT Institutional Planning Department}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} $p<0.05$, \sym{**} $p<0.01$, \sym{***} \   ($p<0.001$}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Any idea about those brackets? I find it strange they the only ones which look funny.

Comment: `siunitx` tries to align the numbers in brackets.  Try `S[table-align-text-post=false, parse-numbers=false]` - the result is aligned differently, but brackets are typeset closely to the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Since `siunitx` Version 3, a place holder for text before and after numeric values can be input to `table-format` directly. This should be the widest text used in the column to reserve propper spacing. The usage of `\sym` becomes obsolete.

```latex
\begin{tabular}{ S[table-format=1.3{***} ]
```

Alignment can be controlled via the options `table-align-text-before` and `table-align-text-after`:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{ S[table-format=1.3{***}, table-align-text-after=false ]
```

This yields:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\sisetup{input-symbols = ()}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}\centering
        \caption{This is a regression table\label{tab1}}
        \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S[table-format=-4.3{***}, table-align-text-after=false]}}
            \toprule
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Price}\\
            \midrule
            Weight (lbs.) & 1.747{**}&  3.465{***}&   1.747{**}&   3.465{***}\\
            & (0.641)   &   (0.631)   &   (0.641)   & (0.631)     \\
            \addlinespace
            Mileage (mpg) &    -49.51   & 21.85   &    -49.51   & 21.85     \\
            & (86.16)   &   (74.22)   &   (86.16)   &   (74.22)     \\
            \addlinespace
            Car type  &     &    3673.1{***}&       &    3673.1{***}\\
            &       &   (684.0)   &     &   (684.0)     \\
            \addlinespace
            Constant  &    1946.1   &   -5853.7   &    1946.1   &   -5853.7     \\
            &    (3597.0)   &  (3377.0)   &  (3597.0)   &  (3377.0)     \\
            \midrule
            Observations  &    {74}   &    {74}   &    {74}   &    {74}     \\
            Adjusted \(R^{2}\)& 0.273   & 0.478   & 0.273   & 0.478     \\
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Source: UCT Institutional Planning Department}\\
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize {*} $p<0.05$, {**} $p<0.01$, {***} \   $p<0.001$}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: result from the code snipped above]