# How to make numbers in the table bigger?

Tags: tables, fonts

I have a rather wide table (13 columns) that I convert from Excel to LaTex. I use resizebox to make the table fit within the page. But the numbers in the table are minuscule. Any recommendations on how to change that? I don't want the caption text to change and the table should also fit into the page.

Here is my basic code:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{longtable}
%*****The commands below define new column types suited for variable description************
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}



\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \begin{table}[htb]
                \centering
                \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
                \caption[.]{\textbf{This is a test table}\newline
                    \footnotesize{  This table reports estimates from the following panel regression model:
                        \begin{equation*}
                        \begin{split}
                        ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm_{ijt}=\alpha_0+\beta_{1}\times FirmSize_{ijt} +\beta_{2} \times FirmAge_{it}+\beta_{3} \times Profit_{jt} \times FirmSize_{j} \\
                        + \beta_{4} \times FirmAge_{ijt} \times Profits_{j} + 
                        \beta_{5} \times Market_{ijt} \times Profits_{j} +           
                        \phi_{j}+\gamma_{t}+\varepsilon_{ijt}
                        \end{split}
                        \end{equation*}
                        A big caption (9 lines of text) goes here describing all the variables
                    }
                }           
                \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc|cccc|cccc|}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Some text here}} \\
\midrule
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\midrule
& ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm & ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm \\
\midrule
& ABCD & ABCD & ABCD & ABCD & EFGH & EFGH & EFGH & EFGH & PQRS & PQRS & PQRS & PQRS \\
\midrule
FirmSize & 0.027*** & 0.023*** & 0.023*** & 0.023*** & 0.008*** & 0.033*** & 0.043*** & 0.063*** & 0.025*** & 0.043*** & 0.053*** & 0.063*** \\
& (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) \\
FirmAge & -0.096*** & -0.097*** & -0.097*** & -0.098*** & -0.097*** & -0.088*** & -0.088*** & -0.088*** & -0.097*** & -0.097*** & -0.088*** & -0.068*** \\
& (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) \\
Mkt   & 0.043 & 0.053 & 0.166** & 0.035 & 0.027 & 0.043 & 0.056 & 0.012 & 0.032 & 0.044 & 0.118 & 0.020 \\
& (0.088) & (0.088) & (0.228) & (0.088) & (0.090) & (0.089) & (0.092) & (0.091) & (0.089) & (0.089) & (0.215) & (0.090) \\
Share & 0.114 & 0.011 & 0.011 & 0.999 & 0.127 & 0.035 & 0.044 & 0.056 & 0.312 & 0.039 & 0.056 & 0.679 \\
& (0.124) & (0.119) & (0.119) & (0.308) & (0.121) & (0.119) & (0.119) & (0.119) & (0.120) & (0.119) & (0.120) & (0.285) \\
Profits & 0.3*** & 0.276*** & 0.264*** & 0.264*** & 0.267*** & 0.254*** & 0.265*** & 0.265*** & 0.268*** & 0.269*** & 0.266*** & 0.265*** \\
& (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) \\
FirmSize x Profits & -0.011*** &       &       &       & 0.010*** &       &       &       & 0.013*** &       &       &  \\
& (0.003) &       &       &       & (0.003) &       &       &       & (0.004) &       &       &  \\
FirmAge x Profits &       & -0.042** &       &       &       & 0.049 &       &       &       & 0.038 &       &  \\
&       & (0.018) &       &       &       & (0.02) &       &       &       & (0.023) &       &  \\
Mkt x Profits &       &       & -0.668*** &       &       &       & -0.006 &       &       &       & 0.327 &  \\
&       &       & (0.246) &       &       &       & (0.203) &       &       &       & (0.305) &  \\
Share x Profits &       &       &       & -0.560 &       &       &       & 0.123 &       &       &       & 0.327 \\
&       &       &       & (0.355) &       &       &       & (0.435) &       &       &       & (0.500) \\
N     & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 & 60000 \\
adj. R-sq & 0.067 & 0.076 & 0.072 & 0.079 & 0.067 & 0.075 & 0.074 & 0.064 & 0.079 & 0.075 & 0.072 & 0.074 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
Fixed Effects
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Industry, Year}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Industry, Year}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Industry, Year} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

            }

            \end{table}
        \end{scriptsize}
```

Comment: Currently your code isn't compilable. Could you please add the missing code (documentclass)? Apart from that and unrelated to the question: You load several packages twice and the `hyperref` package should generally and with a few exceptions be loaded as the last package. Regarding your question: Using `resizebox` in order to make a table fit onto a page is not recommended, as it leads to inconsistent and in some cases illegibly small font sizes. The contents of the table seem to be placeholders. Could you please also add some information on how wide the actual column headers and contents are?

Comment: Some additional remarks: You might have noticed that `booktabs`'s horizontal lines are incompatible with vertical lines. You might want to consider removing the latter. Also, all the `\multicolumn{1}` command seem to be unnecessary and can be removed.

Comment: I used \documentclass[11pt]{article}. I realize that resizebox is not recommended but I am unable to fit the table into the page without it. The column headers are two words (Super Firms) and each of the numbers are 3 digit numbers with 3 decimals.

Answer (score 2):

(updated answer after the OP provided more-representative numbers and other cells for the table)

There's no need to resort to `\resizebox`. Since your 12 data column-headers are quite wide (and no obvious line-breaking spots seem to be discernable), it's necessary to switch from `\scriptsize` to `\tiny`, though, for the body of the tabular material.

If you use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, don't use vertical lines. No exceptions. At any rates, vertical lines are hardly ever needed in a table. Really.

Do note that it's not necessary, or even a good idea, to cram lots of material in the argument of `\caption`. Much of that material is a legend, not a caption.

The legibility and understandability of the numeric data material would be enhanced if all numbers were aligned on their decimal markers.

Last but definitely not least, you should also make an effort to remove the cruft from the preamble. In the code below, I've tried to make a start. You should definitely determine which packages aren't used at all in your document -- and hence shouldn't be loaded to begin with.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} % or 'letterpaper', as appropriate
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{footnote}
%%\usepackage{epstopdf}  % shouldn't be needed
%%\usepackage{lscape}    % don't load both 'pdflscape' and 'lscape'
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}  % deprecated -- don't use!
%\usepackage{graphicx}   % is loaded by 'rotating' package 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb' package
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{color}      % don't load since 'xcolor' is already loaded
\usepackage{natbib}
%%\usepackage{setspace}  % don't load a package more than once
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xr}
%%\usepackage{longtable} % don't load a package more than once
\usepackage{array} 

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}}  % "variable name"
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\usepackage{hyperref}    % be sure to load this package **last**

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn space    
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,
              font=scriptsize, textfont=bf,
              skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\caption{This is a test table}

This table reports estimates from the following panel regression model:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\vn{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm}_{ijt}
&=\alpha_0+\beta_{1}\times \vn{FirmSize}_{ijt} 
          +\beta_{2}\times \vn{FirmAge}_{it}
          +\beta_{3}\times \vn{Profit}_{jt}   \times \vn{FirmSize}_{j} \\
&\quad    +\beta_{4}\times \vn{FirmAge}_{ijt} \times \vn{Profits}_{j} 
          +\beta_{5}\times \vn{Market}_{ijt}  \times \vn{Profits}_{j} 
          +\phi_{j}+\gamma_{t}+\varepsilon_{ijt}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
A big legend (9 lines of text) goes here describing all the variables. 

\smallskip
\tiny
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    l*{12}{d{2.5}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: Some text here}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} 
& \mc{ABCD\textsuperscript{xyz}Firm} \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
& \mc{ABCD} & \mc{ABCD} & \mc{ABCD} & \mc{ABCD} 
& \mc{EFGH} & \mc{EFGH} & \mc{EFGH} & \mc{EFGH} 
& \mc{PQRS} & \mc{PQRS} & \mc{PQRS} & \mc{PQRS} \\
\midrule
FirmSize & 0.027^{***} & 0.023^{***} & 0.023^{***} & 0.023^{***} & 0.008^{***} & 0.033^{***} & 0.043^{***} & 0.063^{***} & 0.025^{***} & 0.043^{***} & 0.053^{***} & 0.063^{***} \\
& (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) & (0.002) \\
FirmAge & -0.096^{***} & -0.097^{***} & -0.097^{***} & -0.098^{***} & -0.097^{***} & -0.088^{***} & -0.088^{***} & -0.088^{***} & -0.097^{***} & -0.097^{***} & -0.088^{***} & -0.068^{***} \\
& (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) \\
Mkt   & 0.043 & 0.053 & 0.166** & 0.035 & 0.027 & 0.043 & 0.056 & 0.012 & 0.032 & 0.044 & 0.118 & 0.020 \\
& (0.088) & (0.088) & (0.228) & (0.088) & (0.090) & (0.089) & (0.092) & (0.091) & (0.089) & (0.089) & (0.215) & (0.090) \\
Share & 0.114 & 0.011 & 0.011 & 0.999 & 0.127 & 0.035 & 0.044 & 0.056 & 0.312 & 0.039 & 0.056 & 0.679 \\
& (0.124) & (0.119) & (0.119) & (0.308) & (0.121) & (0.119) & (0.119) & (0.119) & (0.120) & (0.119) & (0.120) & (0.285) \\
Profits & 0.3^{***} & 0.276^{***} & 0.264^{***} & 0.264^{***} & 0.267^{***} & 0.254^{***} & 0.265^{***} & 0.265^{***} & 0.268^{***} & 0.269^{***} & 0.266^{***} & 0.265^{***} \\
& (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) & (0.026) \\
FirmSize$\times$Profits & -0.011^{***} &       &       &       & 0.010^{***} &       &       &       & 0.013^{***} &       &       &  \\
& (0.003) &       &       &       & (0.003) &       &       &       & (0.004) &       &       &  \\
FirmAge$\times$Profits &       & -0.042** &       &       &       & 0.049 &       &       &       & 0.038 &       &  \\
&       & (0.018) &       &       &       & (0.02) &       &       &       & (0.023) &       &  \\
Mkt$\times$Profits &       &       & -0.668^{***} &       &       &       & -0.006 &       &       &       & 0.327 &  \\
&       &       & (0.246) &       &       &       & (0.203) &       &       &       & (0.305) &  \\
Share$\times$Profits &       &       &       & -0.560 &       &       &       & 0.123 &       &       &       & 0.327 \\
&       &       &       & (0.355) &       &       &       & (0.435) &       &       &       & (0.500) \\
\addlinespace
N  & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} 
   & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} & \mc{60000} \\
adj.\ R-sq & 0.067 & 0.076 & 0.072 & 0.079 & 0.067 & 0.075 & 0.074 & 0.064 & 0.079 & 0.075 & 0.072 & 0.074 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
Fixed Effects
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Industry, Year}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Industry, Year}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Industry, Year} \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. The sidewaystable works nicely but the table does not fit into the page (both width and length wise). The numbers I showed in the code were just place holders. Each of the 1's is a 2 or 3 digit number with 3 decimal places. I tried /small and it still overflows.

Comment: @DShill - If the numbers, columns, and rows of your sample code aren't representative of what your real table is about, then indeed my answer will likely be less than fully useful. Do you want me to delete it? Alternatively, would you mind editing your query to post a more realistic code sample?

Comment: I edited the query with more realistic numbers and variable names. Thanks

Comment: @DShill - I've updated my answer. My main recommendation to you is, try to find simpler/more compact material for the header cells.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using neither `scriptsize` nor `lscape`, but rather `sidewaystable`.

You can fill up the width using `tabular*`.

In any case, converting a table from Excel to LaTeX requires some handwork.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}

\caption[This is a test table]{This is a test table}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\footnotesize
  This table reports estimates from the following panel regression model:
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
  A_{ijt}&=\alpha_0+\beta_{1}\times B_{ijt} \times C_{j}+\beta_{2} \times
    D_{it}+\beta_{3} \times E_{jt} \times F_{j} \\
  &\qquad+ \beta_{4} \times G_{ijt} \times H_{j} + 
    \beta_{5} \times I_{ijt} \times J_{j} +           
    \phi_{j}+\gamma_{t}+\varepsilon_{ijt}
  \end{split}
  \end{equation*}
  A big caption goes here describing all the variables
\end{minipage}

\medskip

\small
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{12}{c}}
\toprule
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\midrule
  & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y \\
  & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari & Vari \\
\midrule
A   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
B   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
C   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
D   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
E   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
F   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
G   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
H   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
I   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
N   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\midrule
AR  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(l){10-13}
XYZ
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440524/how-to-make-numbers-in-the-table-bigger?noredirect=1#comment1107736_440524), here is a suggestion using `sidewaystable` in combination with the `siunitx` package to align the numbers:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}



\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
   \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
   \caption{\textbf{This is a test table}}\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
   {\footnotesize  This table reports estimates from the following panel regression model:
       \begin{equation*}
       \begin{split}
       A_{ijt}=\alpha_0+\beta_{1}\times B_{ijt} \times C_{j}+\beta_{2} \times
       D_{it}+\beta_{3} \times E_{jt} \times F_{j} \\
       + \beta_{4} \times G_{ijt} \times H_{j} + 
       \beta_{5} \times I_{ijt} \times J_{j} +           
       \phi_{j}+\gamma_{t}+\varepsilon_{ijt}
       \end{split}
       \end{equation*}
       A big caption goes here describing all the variables
    }

    \centering \medskip
    \begin{tabular}{l*{12}{S[table-format=3.3]}}
    \toprule
    & {1}     & {2}     & {3}    & {4}     & {5}     & {6}     & {7}     & {8}     & {9}     & {10}    & {11}    & {12} \\
    \midrule
    & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y} & {Y}  \\
    & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari} & {Vari}  \\
    \midrule
    A     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456     & 123.456    & 123.456 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    B     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    C     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    D     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    E     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    F     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    G     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    H     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    I     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\[3pt]
    N     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    AR    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13} 
    {XYZ}   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Some text} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can we have numbers with characters? That is if I had to report significance stars next to the coefficients, I get errors

Comment: @DShill: You might want to have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180001/134144